# Sequelize beforeConnect hook with sequelize-typescript not running

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typescript1.8, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to run sequelize beforeConnect hook to be able to change credential on running sequelize instance. I am literally copy paste what is written in sequelize docs:

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#connection-hooks

```
            this.sequelize = new Sequelize({ config } as SequelizeOptions);
            this.sequelize.beforeConnect((config) => {
                config.password = "postgres";
            })
```

I am using `"sequelize": "6.5.0"` and `"sequelize-typescript": "2.1.0"`

It is displaying this error:

> Property 'beforeConnect' does not exist on type 'Sequelize'. Did you mean to access the static member 'Sequelize.beforeConnect' instead?ts(2576)

And if I try to access it as static method it just does not run
`Sequelize.beforeConnect(...)`

*At least when I use it as a static method it compiles but says that `config.password` is a read only. Which is not because the sequalize docs shows exactly this one. Is that just bad types from `sequelize-typescript`?*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm suffering from the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this GitHub link, it helped me to resolve the beforeConnect issue.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12646

The workaround works for me for Sequelize v6.6.2 and Sequelize-typescript v2.1.0.